# Parse Error on Vivado while simulation an EDIF file

Tags: vivado, yosys

I have generated an EDIF file using Yosys, and I'd like to do post-synthesis simulation on Vivado. However, I get the following parse error. Do you have any idea, what would cause this error?
I'm using Yosys 0.9+3981 and Vivado 2018.3
[Parse Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct86x.png)

```
(cell (rename id00064 "aes_key_regs(perfectly_interleaved="yes")(1,3)")
  (cellType GENERIC)
  (view VIEW_NETLIST
    (viewType NETLIST)
    (interface
      (port RstxBI (direction INPUT))
      (port (array KeyToSboxOutxDO 8) (direction OUTPUT))
      (port KeySchedulexSI (direction INPUT))
      (port (array KeyOutxDO 8) (direction OUTPUT))
      (port (array KeyInxDI 8) (direction INPUT))
      (port (array KeyInterleavedxDI 8) (direction INPUT))
      (port (array K03xDO 8) (direction OUTPUT))
      (port ClkxCI (direction INPUT))
    )
```

Comment: Can you provide the part of the design that's causing this?

Comment: @gatecat do you mean the whole cell that has this error? I just added the part of the cell definition

Comment: What would be useful is the Verilog or other input that produced that cell

Comment: That's the VHDL code I'm working on, I convert it to ilang using  the commercial version and then generated the edif out of it https://github.com/hgrosz/aes-dom/blob/master/aes_key_regs.vhdl